# Convert string to datetime.time object

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I'm persisting `datetime.time` objects in MongoDB using MongoEngine and am developing a field for this.

Converting a Python `datetime.time` object into a MongoDB representation is fairly easy (`str(datetime.time(14, 30))`), but how should I convert it back to a native Python type from a string? Is there a built-in method for doing so?

I'd like to avoid writing a regex for this if possible, but if that's the solution, that's the solution.

Comment: [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`datetime.strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to get a `datetime`, and then the [`time()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) to get the `time`.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this the purpose of `DateTimeField` (references: [Defining Documents](https://mongoengine-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/defining-documents.html) and [API Reference](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/apireference.html)). I haven't worked with MongoEngine or worked with MongoDB in python, so I am not sure if I am missing something from my quick read of the documentation.

Is there any reason you are not using the MongoDB PyMongo and MongoClient? Their [documentation](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/tutorial.html) states:

> Note that documents can contain native Python types (like datetime.datetime instances) which will be automatically converted to and from the appropriate BSON types.

Comment: I'm storing a `time` object, not a `datetime` object. I want only the hours, minutes, seconds, and timezone, and don't want the date in any way, so it's more efficient to store things this way, IMO.